# Eclipse throwing Permission denied Exception in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I am facing a problem with Ubuntu as I am new to Ubuntu.

What I have done is, Installed Eclipse Kepler and android-sdks in /home and set SDK location to /home/android/android-sdks in Eclipse (Window -> Preferences -> Android). everything is working fine. later I understood that SDK is taking too much hard disk space (nearly 6 GB) so I have copied android-sdks to /media/Softwares/android folder and deleted from /home/android.

now When updating SDK location in Eclipse to /media/Softwares/android/android-sdks, I am getting below Exception

[2013-12-11 22:38:05 - adb] Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/media/Softwares/android/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied' while attempting to get adb version from '/media/Softwares/android/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb'

please help me to solve this issue...

thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should not have put your stuff into media directory. This is where the system mounts drives. I believe '/usr' would be a more suitable place for your sdk.
2. if you have problems with access to some directory, navigate to it from the terminal and use 'chmod' command.

chmod 777 -R xxx (where xxx is a name of the directory you want to change access rights to) will give all possible access rights to all users

Comment: Just to note, this works for OSX users as well as Linux users. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: saved my day, even if it was installed without sudo... anyway, thanks it helped me on ubuntu 14.10 & studio